# need redirection 301 .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What Code do i use on .htaccess file to redirect 301 these domains:

https://example.com/* -> https://www.example.com/* -> https://ww.example.com/* -> https://wvw.example.com/* = to https://ww1.example.com/*

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need a redirection rule and one condition per host name:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ww\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://ww1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301]
```

If you actually want to redirect *all* requested hosts your http server responds to over to "ww1.example.com" then this can be simplified:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ww1\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://ww1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301]
```

Here is the documentation, it helps a lot to actually read the documentation of the tool you use: 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I tried this : but there is no redirection on all urls: for example : ww.example.com/page-1 or ww.example.com/categorie/page are not redirecting to ww1.example.com/page-1 or ww1.example.com/categorie/page    you gave me fo just the home page i want for the whole urls (domain.com/*)                             
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ww\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://ww1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301]

Comment: No, above rules do not just redirect the "home page", they unconditionally redirect _all_ requests to hosts not satisfying the condition. I assume you are looking at cached results in your browser.

Comment: I tried this RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ww1\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://ww1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301] still not working redirection for other urls still the same without redirection to ww1.example.com/****

Comment: Maybe that rule set is not considered at all in your setup? How did you make sure you know it _is_ actually evaluated?